# Size of parity automata and Buchi automata from linear time mu-calculus?

Tags: automata, linear-temporal-logic

Given a linear time mu-calculus formula, there are many works on transforming the formula to Buchi or Parity automaton.  Using the best algorithm, what is the size of the resulting Buchi automaton and parity automaton?

Suppose the size of the formula is n which is the number of subformulae, then, how many states and transition rules in Buchi automata and Parity automaton?

Comment: What research have you done so far, and what have you found so far? What's the best result you've found so far? Have you found any result on the size of the resulting automaton for any transformation algorithm? We want you to do some research before asking here, and to share in the question what research you've done.

Comment: ...also, what is a linear-time mu-calculus formula?